# Does a command-line client exist for Microsoft Jet database engine?

Tags: command-line, jet, ms-jet-ace

Is there such a thing as a shell-based command-line client for Microsoft's [Jet database engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine)?

Something similar to [SQLite 3.x](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) (sqlite3.exe) for SQLite.

Answer (score 3):

Will PowerShell be suitable?  Fellow [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Most_Valuable_Professional) Richard Siddaway has [started a very interesting series of blog postings on using PowerShell and Access.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/tags/Access/default.aspx)   You can ignore the Office 2010 tag on his blog postings.   Also note that I know nothing about PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

This may suit:

> Cscript.exe is a command-line version
>   of the Windows Script Host that
>   provides command-line options for
>   setting script properties.
>
> With Cscript.exe, you can run scripts
>   by typing the name of a script file at
>   the command prompt. Like Microsoft
>   Internet Explorer, Windows Script Host
>   serves as a controller of Windows
>   Script compliant scripting engines,
>   but Windows Script Host has very low
>   memory requirements. Windows Script
>   Host is ideal for both interactive and
>   non-interactive scripting needs, such
>   as logon scripting and administrative
>   scripting.
>
> Windows Script Host supports scripts
>   written in VBScript or JScript.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wsh_runfromcommandprompt.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Mmm, not really what I was looking for. I am aware of cscript, although I go with python + pywin32 + ado for that.

Comment: I was going to answer with VBScript, which is about as close as you're going to get to scripting Jet/ACE database interaction from the commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Entering the conversation here 10 years after the original question, but I've played with a couple of tools that should work:

1. **YouAccess** (http://youaccess.sourceforge.net): "YouAccess is a free (donationware) lifesaver console µapplication intended for SQL management of Microsoft® Access™ databases from command line, including creating them."
2. **JetSQLConsole** (https://sourceforge.net/projects/jetsqlconsole): "A command line/console interface for Microsoft Access databases, very similar to the MySQL client application."

Comment: Here's another option for macOS users. *Yes, you read that correctly.* **jetread** (https://eggerapps.at/jetread): "... a simple command line tool for macOS that allows you to read MDB and ACCDB databases from the command line."